# XPM and CME are not properly rendering on InternetExplorer 10 and 11 version

Tags: cme, experience-manager

We are using SDL Trdion 2013 SP1 and when trying to edit content through XPM then CME is not rendering properly, for reference see the attached image.

[image]

Thanks
Nash

Comment: What is your question? Also, what have you tried, e.g. looked at what JS loads/fails to load via developer tools?

Comment: Ribbon bar does not render properly, no menu is clickable and this is happening only when we are using IE 10 and 11 version.

Comment: Hi Nash, you haven't added a lot of detail here and I don't see a question. Perhaps you could add more detail or raise this with SDL support instead?

Comment: Detail which I can provide you is that UI of CME is not properly rendering on IE 10 and 11 version as you can see in the attached screenshot, whereas every thing is working fine on other browsers.

Comment: What have you done to try and resolve the issue? Can you see any JavaScript errors?

Comment: Have you tried just deleting the local cache? Or hitting F5?

Comment: @Naresh: As others are saying you may add more details in the question itself along with what all you have tried so far. Also check for what all are getting blocked.try on some other machine with IE 10/11 to verify if any firewall or network policy is blocking something on IE specifically. Also verify if there is any specific IE setting which should not be enabled/disabled.
Furthermore, you may try to debug the UI by referring this great link: https://sdltridionworld.com/images/SDLWCMS_Debugging%20the%20Tridion%202011%20CME_tcm89-20439.pdf

Answer (score 5):

I see a similar ribbon toolbar when certain versions of IE run in compatibility mode.

[image: Homepage in XPM with Compatibility Mode On]

Even when not set explicitly, IE may automatically display certain (all or Intranet) sites in Compatibility Mode based on the check boxes in `Tools` > `Compatibility View Settings`.

Try turning the setting off for the specific browser as well as follow the other browser settings in the documentation.

Comment: Perfect.... :), up vote from me.

Answer (score 2):

When working with virtual workstations, often internal websites like the Tridion CME are forced to run in compatibility mode IE 7.

This is a setting that can be turned off, or the Tridion CME environments and publish targets should be whitelisted :)